# Open new chrome window with applescript alfred workflow

Tags: applescript, alfred

```
on alfred_script(q)

tell application "Google Chrome"
    if it is closed then
      activate
    end if
    else 
        make new window
        tell application "System Events" to set frontmost of process "Google Chrome" to true
        activate
    end else
end tell

end alfred_script
```

What is wrong is my appleScript code

I just want to open new terminal if google chrome is open otherwise just run the google chrome.

It will be a alfred work flow.

Comment: The if and else nesting isn't correct. The `else` should be before the `end if` (which can be removed) and instead of `end else` use `end if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to work with process of an application.

```
on alfred_script(q)
    
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        if its running is true then make new window
        activate
    end tell
    
end alfred_script
```

Note: you can omit *is true* as well. **if its running then make new window**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any of your conditions. This will launch the app and make a new window if it's not running. If it is running, it will be brought frontmost and a new window will be made.

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    make new window
end tell
```

That said, you will probably end up with too many blank windows. This will check whether `Google Chrome` is already running.  If it is, it will bring it frontmost. If there's an existing window or there's no window a new one will be created. If Chrome is not running it will be launched with a new window (its default start state).

```
tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains "Google Chrome"
set chromeRunning to result

tell application "Google Chrome"
    activate
    if chromeRunning then
        make new window
    end if
end tell
```